# SCCM SQL Query Join of Multiple tables

Tags: sql, join, sccm

Here is a Question for all of you SQL brains out there.  I am joining several tables from my SCCM database.  I am trying to join multiple tables.  Here is my query:

```
SELECT v_R_System.Name0,
  v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.ChassisTypes0,
  v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.Manufacturer0,
  v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.Model0,
  v_R_System.Operating_System_Name_and0,
  v_R_User.User_Name0,
  v_UsersPrimaryMachines.UserResourceID ,
  v_R_User.Full_User_Name0,
  v_R_System.Is_Virtual_Machine0,
  v_GS_X86_PC_MEMORY.TotalPhysicalMemory0,
  v_RA_System_IPAddresses.IP_Addresses0
FROM v_R_System
LEFT JOIN v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE
ON v_R_System.ResourceID = v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.ResourceID
LEFT JOIN v_RA_System_IPAddresses
ON v_R_System.ResourceID = v_RA_System_IPAddresses.ResourceID
LEFT JOIN v_GS_X86_PC_MEMORY
ON v_R_System.ResourceID = v_GS_X86_PC_MEMORY.ResourceID
LEFT JOIN v_UsersPrimaryMachines
ON v_R_System.ResourceID = v_UsersPrimaryMachines.MachineID
LEFT JOIN v_R_User
ON v_UsersPrimaryMachines.UserResourceID = v_R_User.ResourceID
WHERE (v_RA_System_IPAddresses.IP_Addresses0 NOT LIKE '%:%')
```

In my results, I am getting the same machine listed multiple times for the same computer.  I would expect to see this for every user listed for the computer.  So, the issue I have is that I want all computers to be listed at least once.  Computers that match RecsourceID in the UsersPrimaryMachine table should show for as many primary users are listed that have a matching UserResourceID in the v_R_User table.  I am guessing I need to change a JOIN somewhere to INNER JOIN.  But as soon as I do, I only list the 2 CLIENT machines 2 times each.

```
Name0   ChassisTypes0   Manufacturer0   Model0  Operating_System_Name_and0  User_Name0  UserResourceID  Full_User_Name0 Is_Virtual_Machine0 TotalPhysicalMemory0    IP_Addresses0
SCCM-2K12       1   No Enclosure    NULL    Microsoft Windows NT Server 6.2 NULL    NULL    NULL    1   4193780 192.168.91.15
WIN8-CLIENT1    1   No Enclosure    NULL    Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 6.2 (Tablet Edition)   puser   2063597571  Paul User   1   1048052 192.168.91.103
WIN8-CLIENT1    1   No Enclosure    NULL    Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 6.2 (Tablet Edition)   juser   2063597572  John User   1   1048052 192.168.91.103
WIN8-CLIENT1    1   No Enclosure    NULL    Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 6.2 (Tablet Edition)   NULL    2080374786  NULL    1   1048052 192.168.91.103
WIN8-CLIENT1    1   No Enclosure    NULL    Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 6.2 (Tablet Edition)   NULL    2080374787  NULL    1   1048052 192.168.91.103
WIN8-CLIENT1    1   No Enclosure    NULL    Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 6.2 (Tablet Edition)   NULL    2080374789  NULL    1   1048052 192.168.91.103
WIN8-CLIENT1    1   No Enclosure    NULL    Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 6.2 (Tablet Edition)   NULL    2080374790  NULL    1   1048052 192.168.91.103
WIN81-CLIENT2   1   No Enclosure    NULL    Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 6.3 (Tablet Edition)   jdoe    2063597570  Jane Doe    1   2096628 192.168.91.100
WIN81-CLIENT2   1   No Enclosure    NULL    Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 6.3 (Tablet Edition)   puser   2063597571  Paul User   1   2096628 192.168.91.100
WIN81-CLIENT2   1   No Enclosure    NULL    Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 6.3 (Tablet Edition)   NULL    2080374786  NULL    1   2096628 192.168.91.100
WIN81-CLIENT2   1   No Enclosure    NULL    Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 6.3 (Tablet Edition)   NULL    2080374787  NULL    1   2096628 192.168.91.100
WIN81-CLIENT2   1   No Enclosure    NULL    Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 6.3 (Tablet Edition)   NULL    2080374789  NULL    1   2096628 192.168.91.100
WIN81-CLIENT2   1   No Enclosure    NULL    Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 6.3 (Tablet Edition)   NULL    2080374790  NULL    1   2096628 192.168.91.100
SCSM-2K12   1   No Enclosure    NULL    Microsoft Windows NT Server 6.2 NULL    NULL    NULL    1   4193780 192.168.91.12
SCSM-SSP    1   No Enclosure    NULL    Microsoft Windows NT Server 6.1 NULL    NULL    NULL    1   2096632 192.168.91.17
MAIL    1   No Enclosure    NULL    Microsoft Windows NT Server 6.2 NULL    NULL    NULL    1   6290932 192.168.91.11
SCOM-2K12-DB    1   No Enclosure    NULL    Microsoft Windows NT Server 6.2 NULL    NULL    NULL    1   4193780 192.168.91.19
SCOM-2K12   1   No Enclosure    NULL    Microsoft Windows NT Server 6.2 NULL    NULL    NULL    1   2096628 192.168.91.18
SCORCH-2K12 1   No Enclosure    NULL    Microsoft Windows NT Server 6.2 NULL    NULL    NULL    1   2096628 192.168.91.21
SCDW-2K12   NULL    NULL    NULL    Microsoft Windows NT Server 6.2 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    192.168.91.13
SHARE-2K8   NULL    NULL    NULL    Microsoft Windows NT Server 6.1 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    192.168.91.16
IIS-2K12    NULL    NULL    NULL    Microsoft Windows NT Server 6.2 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    192.168.91.14
```

Whoever can figure this out would be my hero!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.  I did some more poking around last night.  I ended up with a subselect that got me the results I was looking for.  Thanks for the help.  Here is what I ended up with:

```
SELECT
  S.Name0,
  S.Operating_System_Name_and0,
  S.Is_Virtual_Machine0,
  US.Full_User_Name0,
  US.User_Name0,
  v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.ChassisTypes0,
  v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.Manufacturer0,
  v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.Model0,
  v_GS_X86_PC_MEMORY.TotalPhysicalMemory0,
  v_RA_System_IPAddresses.IP_Addresses0
FROM v_R_System S
LEFT JOIN v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE
ON S.ResourceID = v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.ResourceID
LEFT JOIN v_RA_System_IPAddresses
ON S.ResourceID = v_RA_System_IPAddresses.ResourceID
LEFT JOIN v_GS_X86_PC_MEMORY
ON S.ResourceID = v_GS_X86_PC_MEMORY.ResourceID
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT
  U.User_Name0,
  UPM.UserResourceID,
  UPM.MachineID,
  U.Full_User_Name0
FROM v_UsersPrimaryMachines UPM
JOIN v_R_User U
ON UPM.UserResourceID = U.ResourceID) US
ON S.ResourceID = US.MachineID
WHERE (v_RA_System_IPAddresses.IP_Addresses0 NOT LIKE '%:%')
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing one of left join `ON v_R_System.ResourceID = v_UsersPrimaryMachines.MachineID`

```
LEFT JOIN v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE
ON v_R_System.ResourceID = v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.ResourceID
LEFT JOIN v_RA_System_IPAddresses
ON v_R_System.ResourceID = v_RA_System_IPAddresses.ResourceID
LEFT JOIN v_GS_X86_PC_MEMORY
ON v_R_System.ResourceID = v_GS_X86_PC_MEMORY.ResourceID
LEFT JOIN v_UsersPrimaryMachines
ON v_R_System.ResourceID = v_UsersPrimaryMachines.MachineID
LEFT JOIN v_R_User
ON v_UsersPrimaryMachines.UserResourceID = v_R_User.ResourceID
WHERE (v_RA_System_IPAddresses.IP_Addresses0 NOT LIKE '%:%')
```

to:

```
LEFT JOIN v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE
ON v_R_System.ResourceID = v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.ResourceID
LEFT JOIN v_RA_System_IPAddresses
ON v_R_System.ResourceID = v_RA_System_IPAddresses.ResourceID
LEFT JOIN v_GS_X86_PC_MEMORY
ON v_R_System.ResourceID = v_GS_X86_PC_MEMORY.ResourceID
LEFT JOIN v_UsersPrimaryMachines
ON v_R_System.ResourceID = v_UsersPrimaryMachines.UserResourceID
LEFT JOIN v_R_User
ON v_UsersPrimaryMachines.UserResourceID = v_R_User.ResourceID
WHERE (v_RA_System_IPAddresses.IP_Addresses0 NOT LIKE '%:%')
```

**Full Query**

```
SELECT v_R_System.Name0,
  v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.ChassisTypes0,
  v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.Manufacturer0,
  v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.Model0,
  v_R_System.Operating_System_Name_and0,
  v_R_User.User_Name0,
  v_UsersPrimaryMachines.UserResourceID ,
  v_R_User.Full_User_Name0,
  v_R_System.Is_Virtual_Machine0,
  v_GS_X86_PC_MEMORY.TotalPhysicalMemory0,
  v_RA_System_IPAddresses.IP_Addresses0
FROM v_R_System
LEFT JOIN v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE
ON v_R_System.ResourceID = v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.ResourceID
LEFT JOIN v_RA_System_IPAddresses
ON v_R_System.ResourceID = v_RA_System_IPAddresses.ResourceID
LEFT JOIN v_GS_X86_PC_MEMORY
ON v_R_System.ResourceID = v_GS_X86_PC_MEMORY.ResourceID
LEFT JOIN v_UsersPrimaryMachines
ON v_R_System.ResourceID = v_UsersPrimaryMachines.UserResourceID
LEFT JOIN v_R_User
ON v_UsersPrimaryMachines.UserResourceID = v_R_User.ResourceID
WHERE (v_RA_System_IPAddresses.IP_Addresses0 NOT LIKE '%:%')
```

Comment: Thank you!  The difference was so subtle, it took me a few minutes to figure out what you changed.  But it works like a charm!!  Thanks Again!!

Comment: I take that back.  It didn't work and is not joining all the data from the other tables properly.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I feel like I need to do a standard join between v_UsersPrimaryMachines and v_R_User and then take these results and apply this to the remaining tables that are joined together and join the user data if there is any match to the computer data.

Comment: It should work Paul, What is not working? Can you post Table layout with sample data?